# Event Listener for IME closing

Tags: android, ime

Folks ... Does anyone know if there is an event I can listen for when the IME is closing or has closed/collapsed?  If so, can you point me to some sample code?

I have an Activity with several EditText widgets and want to call a method when the IME has been dismissed.

Many Thanks!